# Load data when change neon-page

Tags: ajax, polymer-1.0

I'm new in Polymer and I trying to do mobile app use Polymer and Cordova.
I use neon-animated-pages for pretty animation, and now I have some issue with iron-ajax. When I open project in browser on localhost:8080 all my pages already loaded and if I change page I want to make iron-ajax request. How can i do this?

example index.html

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
<template>
    <style>
        // some style
    </style>
    <app-header-layout fullbleed>
        <app-header>
            <app-toolbar>
                <div main-title>Title</div>
                <paper-input label="page" value="{{page::change}}"></paper-input>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
        </app-header>
        <div class="content">
            <neon-animated-pages id="page"
                                 selected="{{page}}" 
                                 attrForSelected="index" 
                                 entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation" 
                                 exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
                <neon-animatable index="0"><login-app name="login"></login-app></neon-animatable>
                <neon-animatable index="1"><profile-page name="profile"></profile-page></neon-animatable>
                <neon-animatable index="2"><secondary-page name="secondary"></secondary-page></neon-animatable>
            </neon-animated-pages>
        </div>
            <footer>
                &copy; Polymer project
            </footer>

        </app-header-layout>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-app',
        behaviors: [GlobalsBehaviour],
        properties: {
            page: {
                type: Number,
                reflectToAttribute: true,
                value: 0
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And example some page with iron-ajax:

```
<dom-module id="secondary-page">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <div>secondary PAGE</div>
    <div>Var value - {{my}}</div>
    <iron-ajax
                id="login"
                url="https://www.some.url/"
                method="get"></iron-ajax>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'secondary-page',
        properties: {
            my: {
                type: String,
                value: 'my'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```